# Subject.doAs with complex code

Tags: java, security, jaas

In the javadocs it states that AccessController.doPrivileged() is called

Further in the javadocs for AccessController.doPrivileged it states...

"Be *very* careful in your use of the "privileged" construct, and always remember to make the privileged code section as small as possible."

What then are the implications for having code within the privileged construct which is not even remotely on the small side?

Comment: The context is not specifically the size/loc of the code, but the coverage of the privileged construct on the code. You have to make absolutely sure that you don't accidentally cover code which isn't supposed to be executed with that privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `Subject.doAs` is to change the `Subject` of the current `AccessControlContext` (acc). It should not change permissions. The API docs of `doAs` say "using the retrieved context", and if you look at the source code, it is combining the acc from `AccessController.getContext` with the subject.

In fact, the acc needs to be privileged for the call to succeed.

The problem with is large sections of code running with elevated permissions is that it is opposed to the Principle of Least Privilege. There is an increased chance that somewhere an adversary can slip in some malicious operation.

Comment: That makes sense now. It isn't a technical reason for keeping the code section small, it is in relation to the nature of the operation. As BalusC mentioned above to ensure that code coverage doesn't stray past the boundaries of what should be executed. Excellent, thank you both...